# set 'secure' flag to JSESSION id cookie

Tags: tomcat6, jsessionid

I want to set 'secure'  flag to JSESSIONID cookie . Is there a configuration in tomcat 6 for this ?

I tried by setting 'secure="true"'  in  'Connector' (8080)  element of server.xml , but it creates problems ....thats Connection is getting reset .

Note that in my application , the JSESSIONID is getting created in 'http' mode ( index page ) , when the user logins , it will switch into 'https' mode.

Comment: this is the correct behaviour of Tomcat. Your session will begin at HTTP time with the JSESSIONID, this will change to a different one at HTTPS. So what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Did you figure it out eventually ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using tomcat 6 you can do the following workaround

```
String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; secure ; HttpOnly");
```

see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly for more information

Comment: I know this is an old answer but where exactly would this code snippet go?

Comment: You have two options depending on the version of your servlet api. 1.) Old servlet <3 does not set this flag per automatically. you need to implement this in a filter 2.) new servlet api has a configuration option for that. you donot need to write anything you can set the configuration accordingly.

Comment: This solution would remove other cookies on the response object. `addHeader` method would generate two cookies with the same name and a cookie added through your solution is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute  useHttpOnly="true". In Tomcat9 the default value is true.

Answer (score 0):

For nginx proxy it could be solved easy in nginx config:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}

proxy_cookie_path / "/; secure";
```