# How to flag session cookie as secure (https only) in tomcat 6

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, spring-security, tomcat6

I have done a lot of googeling and could not find an answer. I have tried setting the following in the `web.xml` file in the war with no impact :

```xml
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Adding `useHttpOnly` in the tomcat `context.xml` file works to restrict cookies to http only but I still need to make them secure.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do anything.  As long as the request that starts the session is `https` Tomcat will mark the session cookie as `secure`.

I also looked to see if there was anything that officially documented that fact but I couldn't find it.   But that is the behavior of at least Tomcat 6.0.32 and up.

Here is the code from `org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java` which, at the end of the method, checks to see if the request is secure and if it is, sets the `secure` flag on the cookie:

```java
/**
 * Configures the given JSESSIONID cookie.
 *
 * @param cookie The JSESSIONID cookie to be configured
 */
protected void configureSessionCookie(Cookie cookie) {
    cookie.setMaxAge(-1);

    Context ctxt = getContext();

    String contextPath = null;
    if (ctxt != null && !getConnector().getEmptySessionPath()) {
        if (ctxt.getSessionCookiePath() != null) {
            contextPath = ctxt.getSessionCookiePath();
        } else {
            contextPath = ctxt.getEncodedPath();
        }
    }
    if ((contextPath != null) && (contextPath.length() > 0)) {
        cookie.setPath(contextPath);
    } else {
        cookie.setPath("/");
    }

    if (ctxt != null && ctxt.getSessionCookieDomain() != null) {
        cookie.setDomain(ctxt.getSessionCookieDomain());
    }

    if (isSecure()) {
        cookie.setSecure(true);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: you can manually try to set this by yourself by using a filter etc.. you can check an example from
[set 'secure' flag to JSESSION id cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566264/set-secure-flag-to-jsession-id-cookie/11933595#11933595)

Comment: Just want to confirm that: Viewing your session cookies in a browser dev tool of your choice (Safari's Webinspector in my case) will tell you that the cookie is indeed a secure-only cookie