# How to set secure cookie in Java/Spring MVC on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, heroku

Based on my research, in order to have all cookies be secure, server.xml needs to be modified, but heroku's webapp runner doesn't give you access to it.  Is there a way to do it through a servlet filter or some spring mvc filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, require HTTPS - in that case Tomcat does the right thing (with the session cookie, at least - see [How to flag session cookie as secure (https only) in tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767526/how-to-flag-session-cookie-as-secure-https-only-in-tomcat-6)). On Heroku, the trick is making sure Tomcat knows the request is secure - by default on Heroku it doesn't, since the inbound request is proxied, and SSL is handled in the routing mesh. I.e., `request.isSecure()` will return `false`

However, `webapp-runner` lets you specify a `context.xml`; in there you can configure `RemoteIpValve` so that Tomcat will pick up various `x_forwarded` headers and adjust the request accordingly (i.e., if an HTTPS request is made to the routing mesh, `request.isSecure()` will now be true, even through Tomcat only saw the request as HTTP. I did something similar, documented here: [SSL redirects in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397034/ssl-redirects-in-heroku/13649976#13649976)

Hope that helps.