# Spring Boot JSESSIONID secure flag not set over HTTPS

Tags: cookies, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, jsessionid, sticky-session

We have build a Cloud Foundry app using Liberty for Java.  When testing the app we found that the SSL cookie did not have the secure flag set.

Issue:
The JSESSIONID did not have the Secure flag set while the _VCAP_ID had the Secure flag set

We have used Spring Boot to develop the app and according to the documentation we just need to secure the cookie flag in a property file: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

RESOLUTION:
We have ended up fixing the issue by following this post [Add secure flag to JSESSIONID cookie in spring automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39252924/add-secure-flag-to-jsessionid-cookie-in-spring-automatically)

Does anyone know if there is an issue with Cloud Foundry or Liberty related to not being able to set the SSL cookie secure flag on both JSESSIONID and _VCAP_ID at the same time over HTTPS?

Comment: I'm confused, after your change, weren't both _VCAP_ID and JSESSIONID cookies secure? Or did your resolution somehow remove the Secure flag from  _VCAP_ID?

If they're both secure, why ask the question " not being able to set the SSL cookie secure flag on both JSESSIONID and _VCAP_ID at the same time"